# Writing a custom SQL function that manipulates the return value of another SQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a SQL function that will apply `ts_rank` for the given parameters, and return the `ts_rank` multiplied by 4.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION scale_ts_rank_to_intensity(vector tsvector, query tsquery) RETURNS float AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT ts_rank(vector, query) * 4;
END; $$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I'm getting this error output:

```
SQL State  : 42601
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
  Position: 117
Location   : db/migration/V57__modify_product_search_scores.sql (/Users/samphillips/Projects/itravel/nucleo/file:/var/folders/js/f6hx8f091c1fjnr908gxcv5w0000gn/T/sbt_46b3ed5/target/bcb357bb/nucleo-database_2.12-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/db/migration/V57__modify_product_search_scores.sql)
Line       : 55
Statement  : CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION scale_ts_rank_to_intensity(vector tsvector, query tsquery) RETURNS float AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT ts_rank(vector, query) * 4;
END; $$
LANGUAGE SQL

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.handleException(DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.java:268)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.executeStatement(DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.java:215)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.execute(DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.java:122)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:77)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.doMigrateGroup(DbMigrate.java:367)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
  Position: 117
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2178)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:235)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.ParsedSqlStatement.execute(ParsedSqlStatement.java:111)
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.executeStatement(DefaultSqlScriptExecutor.java:203)
    ... 72 more

Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-0"
```

Edit: I just changed the `LANGUAGE` to: `plpgsql`

Now, I am getting this error (a run-time error from Hasura, but I don't think that's important here).

```
          "error": {
            "exec_status": "FatalError",
            "hint": "If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.",
            "message": "query has no destination for result data",
            "status_code": "42601",
            "description": null
          },
```

Comment: Are you asking about both postgesql and the Microsoft SQL server?

Comment: Have you created and tested the function from a command line such as psql?

Comment: My mistake, I fixed the tags. 

I just tried that, got this response:
```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 3:     SELECT ts_rank(vector, query) * 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION scale_ts_rank_to_intensity(vector tsvector, query tsquery) RETURNS float AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN(SELECT ts_rank(vector, query) * 4);
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

This version seems to be working. I had to change the language to `plpgsql`, which makes sense because the `ts_rank` function is a Postgres function. I'm not sure why it was causing a syntax error, though. Maybe someone with  more SQL experience could explain that.

Then, I needed to `RETURN` the selected value. Doing both of these things seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: `RETURN SELECT ..` is illegal because a SELECT-statement can return more than 1 value. You need to rwrite this to (ad you did) to: `RETURN (SELECT …)`.   Compare this to `SELECT * FROM SELECT 1;` and `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1) as x;`.

Comment: SQL functions do NOT have "begin ... end".  Just use "AS $$ select ...; $$; Also, if multiple rows can be returned you will need  "returns setof float"